# Fixing a tab order issue

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a VBA userform with a number of combo boxes and textboxes which sit on a multipage control tab.

ComboBox1 is visible and set to TabIndex 26.

Textboxes 2 and 3 are not visible and set to TabIndex 27 & 28.

Textbox 4 is visible and set to TabIndex 29.

I have created code that if ComboBox1 after update is "Yes" then unhide Textboxes 2 and 3, and setfocus on Textbox 2.

However, when executing this UserForm, if I select "Yes" in Combobox1, the tab goes directly to Textbox 4 - skipping Textboxes 2 and 3 (even though they are now visible).

This is happening a few different places in my UserForm1 - sometimes after a Combobox and sometimes after a Textbox.

Have make sure that all tab order is correct.

Have also tried codes for SetFocus.  Have added this at various stages of the sub.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_AfterUpdate()

    If ComboBox1 = "Yes" Then

        Label1148.Visible = True
        Label1149.Visible = True
        Textbox2.Visible = True
        Textbox3.Visible = True
        Me.Textbox2.SetFocus

    End If

End Sub
```

I expect that if Combobox1 is selected as "Yes", then the tab goes directly to the (now) visible Textbox2.

If Combobox1 is selected as "No", then textboxes 2 and 3 remain invisible, and tab goes straight to textbox 4.

Comment: Try `ComboBox1_Change()` event instead.

Comment: Thanks - that works.

Comment: However, what do I do in a similar situation when it's a textbox rather than a combo box thats changing.  Can't change the textbox to a change event or it goes crazy.

Comment: use the `_AfterUpdate` event for the text box.

Comment: For sure, that's what I'm using, but then the whole issue of my tab order doesn't seem to work.  Can't get it to tab across to the newly visible next textbox - instead it skips to the next textbox that was visible before the sub.

Comment: Do you have the tab order set correctly between the controls on the UserForm?

Comment: Yes, if everything was visible when the UserForm was activated, I could tab through in order.  For some reason, when I make certain fields visible on condition of others, I cannot set-focus to the newly visible cells.